# Unable to create file inside directory in runtime

Tags: perl

```
my @file_name = qw(x y x);
my $local_dir ="report_file";
unless(-e $local_dir or mkdir $local_dir) {
    die "Unable to create $local_dir\n";
    my $total_line = "$local_dir/total_line.txt";
    
    open (F1,">>", $total_line) or 
        die "Couldn't open file for writing $total_line: $!\n";

    foreach (@file_name){
        print F1 $_;
    }
    close F1;
}
```

Want to create directory and file at runtime, mkdir is creating directory at runtime but file is not getting created at runtime inside that directory could any please help me for the above issue

Comment: Is using "/" portable?

Comment: Use [File::Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Path) to create a dir.

Comment: mkdir is creating the directory, issue is inside that directory file is not getting created

Comment: Please focus on the part which does not work and make a [mre] for that. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ I.e. try to creaste a file in a hardcoded existing subdirectory. Start with paths in literals instead of constructing from variable. Manually check for existence afterwards, i.e. at first skip the reading attempts.

Comment: @Yunnosch, Yes. Windows accepts both `\ ` and `/` as dir seps, and unix accepts `/`

Comment: More correct would be 'mkdir $dir unless -d $dir; die "Error: can not create $dir" unless -d $dir;`.

Comment: Use variables to avoid repeating dirs/filenames in the code. It would be only one place to make changes. For convenience place variables at the top of you code -- you will not have to jump all over the code in search where you defined variable. You still can use _local_ variables inside loops/blocks of code for convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my($fh,%seen, @unique);

my @data    = qw/x y x/;
my $dir     = 'report_dir';
my $fname   = 'total_line.txt';

mkdir $dir unless -d $dir;
die "Unable to create $dir" unless -d $dir;
    
open $fh, '>>', "$dir/$fname"
    or die "Couldn't open file for writing $dir/$fname: $!";

say $fh $_ for @data;

close $fh;

open $fh, '<', "$dir/$fname"
    or die "Cannot open file for read $dir/$fname :$!";

while ( <$fh> ) {
    chomp;
    push @unique, $_ unless $seen{$_}++;
}

close $fh;

say 'Unique: ', join ', ', @unique;
```

Output

```
Unique: x, y
```

Comment: The following is wasteful, complicated, and doesn't indicate why the directory couldn't be created: `mkdir $dir unless -d $dir;
die "Unable to create $dir" unless -d $dir;` No, you can't just add `$!` to the error messages because `-d $dir` clobbered it. But most importantly, code dumps with no explanations make bad answers.

Comment: Are you OP to say that it is wasteful? Let OP to judge. A good code sample is better half an our explanation of all pitfalls of initial code.

Comment: Just above, you said repeating code is a bad idea, and your code checks if the directory exists *three times*! So you yourself said those two statements are badly written. It really sucks when you teach code you know is bad to newcomers. :( /// A good sample is indeed *part* of a good answer. Don't pretend I said otherwise.

Comment: You need to check your math -- the code check for directory only twice. Of course I could write `mkdir $dir or die "Unable to create $dir" unless -d $dir;` -- but judging by OPs code it would more difficult for him to comprehend this line.

Comment: You call `-d`, `mkdir` and `-d`. That's 3. Only one is necessary. And yeah, that would be just as bad.

Comment: @ikegami [mkdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/mkdir) does not check for existence of the directory.

Comment: huh? Of course it does. And it returns error `EEXIST` when it does. Really, you should [test things](https://pastebin.com/WAiQfhyS) before contradicting others.

Answer (score 5):

You can't possibly reach the code that creates the file.

- If the dir already exists, you skip past the block that would create the file.
- If you successfully create the directory, you skip past the block that would create the file.
- If the creation of the directory isn't successful, you enter the block that would create the file, but the first thing you do is `die` (exit the program).

All you need is this:

```perl
my $dir_qfn = "report_file";

if (!mkdir($dir_qfn)) {
   # If the directory already existed, $!{EEXIST} is true.
   if (!$!{EEXIST}) {
      die("Can't create directory \"$dir_qfn\": $!\n");
   }
}

my $file_qfn = "$dir_qfn/total_line.txt";
open (my $fh, ">>", $file_qfn)
   or die("Can't open \"$file_qfn\": $!\n");

foreach (@file_name){
   print $fh $_;
}
```

Note that checking if the directory exists is wasteful and introduces a needless race condition. It's better to try to just create the directory and simply ignore the error that indicates it already exists.

`%!`, like other global vars, are documented in [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar). As for `EEXIST`, most builtin functions are just thin wrappers for the corresponding unix system call, and `mkdir` is no exception. The manual page for `mkdir` states the following:

> ```
> $ man 2 mkdir
> ...
>
> ERRORS
>
>     EEXIST
>         pathname  already  exists (not necessarily as a directory).
>         This includes the case where pathname is a symbolic link,
>         dangling or not.
>
> ...
> ```

---

The following is a more succinct way to write the above `mkdir` call and error check:

```perl
mkdir($dir_qfn)
   or $!{EEXIST}
   or die("Can't create directory \"$dir_qfn\": $!\n");
```